# Insomnia - how to dynamically get certificates from Azure Keyvault?

Tags: azure, rest, authentication, azure-keyvault, insomnia

I followed [these instructions](https://dev.to/kasuken/a-plugin-for-insomnia-to-retrieve-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-3mip) to connect Insomnia to Azure Keyvault and I was able to get secrets from the Keyvault.

However, I havent been able to find anything helpful online about how I can do the same thing but with a certificate.

The API endpoint I want to call requires a certificate which I need to dynamically get from Keyvault when I call it. Is there a way to do this with Insomnia?